Does taking a Multiclass Archetype make a PC count as a member of that class for effects?
For example, if the party Barbarian has Witch Warden and their Wizard ally took the Witch Dedication, would they count as a 'Witch' when they cast Fireball on the Barbarian giving them the bonus to saves? Would it matter if the spell was cast from a spell slot from the Wizard class vs the Witch Archetype?
Also, if a PC took Sorcerer Dedication and choose Draconic as their Bloodline, would they later qualify for the Dragon Disciple dedication?

Yes
Characters with a multiclass archetype are referred to as any other member of that class in the rules around those archetypes, and there's no rule against that applying generically. For an example from the sorcerer multiclass (emphasis mine):

The sorcerer archetype is a method for anyone to pick up commonly useful spells, such as invisibility and haste. You might choose to become a sorcerer with a bloodline that matches other aspects of your character, such as the dragon bloodline if you have the dragonblood versatile heritage or the undead bloodline if you're a dhampir.

